# Implementing WKWebView / Telerik on IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 Project

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik, ibm-mobilefirst, wkwebview

The main objective here that I'm trying to achieve is to use WkWebView on IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 project instead of UIWebView. This is because of severe memory usage issue cause by UIWebView.

I understand a few points:

1. WkWebView implementation requires Cordova 4.x

   - However IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 only supports till Cordova 3.7.0
2. IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0 is using Cordova 4.x

   - Upgrading to IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0 is not an option for me at the moment, this is because the effort required is huge and the project timeline does not permit (8.0 deprecated a lot of existing features that have pass our testing phase during 7.1)

For that, i found a solution to implement it, that is using Telerik WKWebView that supports WKWebView with Cordova 3.7.0 (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView)

Things i have successfully done so far:

1. Add Telerik WKWebView with no compilation issue
2. Make IBM Mobile First initialisation logic at AppDelegate compatible with Telerik WKWebView's "AppDelegate+WKWebViewPolyfill"

The changes i made is,

IBM Mobile First creates a CDVViewController and add it to rootViewController after the init is successful

```
UIViewController* rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

// Create a Cordova View Controller
CDVViewController* cordovaViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init] ;

cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath];

// Adjust the Cordova view controller view frame to match its parent view bounds
cordovaViewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds;

// Display the Cordova view
[rootViewController addChildViewController:cordovaViewController];
[rootViewController.view addSubview:cordovaViewController.view];
[cordovaViewController didMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
```

i change it to call Telerik WkWebView's createWindowAndStartWebServer

```
//UIViewController* rootViewController = self.window.rootViewController;

// Create a Cordova View Controller
//CDVViewController* cordovaViewController = [[CDVViewController alloc] init] ;

//cordovaViewController.startPage = [[WL sharedInstance] mainHtmlFilePath];

// Adjust the Cordova view controller view frame to match its parent view bounds
//cordovaViewController.view.frame = rootViewController.view.bounds;

// Display the Cordova view
//[rootViewController addChildViewController:cordovaViewController];
//[rootViewController.view addSubview:cordovaViewController.view];
//[cordovaViewController didMoveToParentViewController:rootViewController];
[self createWindowAndStartWebServer:true];
```

I have issue point to the correct path at first('index.html'), so i made changes at CDVViewController.m -> loadSettings from

```
if (self.startPage == nil) {
  self.startPage = @"index.html";
}
```

to

```
if (self.startPage == nil) {
   self.startPage = @"default/index.html";
}
```

For that, all I'm seeing is a white screen after the IBM Mobile First's "Splash Screen" without any error.

Any advice? Any solution?

Comment: As you may already know - this path is not supported by IBM MobileFirst. Just FYI.

Comment: We would like to take upgrading to 8.0 as our last solution. Anyhow to put in WkWebView to 7.1?

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's definitely not supported and will require investigation work... Given that it's not supported this is **not** PMR material and may be considered a feature request. However given the direction in 8.0...